# Custom HOG detector

Tags: c++, opencv

I am done with training stuff. My SVM training file is [here](http://coding-guru.com/OpenCV/trainedSVM.xml) and i am getting SV using following [code](http://coding-guru.com/OpenCV/LinearSVM.cpp)  adopted from some where.

The code is working fine, which can predict person or no person. Now I am trying to detect multiscale using custom detector. I tried to get support vector by extend CVSVM (I am not sure about this code). When i am trying to setSVMDetector. I am getting an error OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (checkDetectorSize()) in setSVMDetector, file opencv\sources\modules\objdetect\src\hog.cpp, line 89

```
LinearSVM svm;
//CvSVM svm;
svm.load("trainedSVM.xml");

vector<float> v;
svm.getSupportVector(v);

 HOGDescriptor hog( Size(64,128), Size(16,16), Size(8,8), Size(8,8), 9);

hog.setSVMDetector(v);
```

Comment: I think you must set block and window sizes for `HOGDescriptor hog;` and this must fit the sizes used for training.

Comment: Now i am getting this Assertion failed (blockSize.width % cellSize.width == 0 && blockSize.height % cellSize.height == 0) in getDescriptorSize,

Comment: Error still there. I added following lines in my code. hog.winSize = Size(64,128);
  hog.cellSize=Size(8,8);
  hog.blockSize =Size(16,16);
  hog.blockStride=Size(8,8);
  hog.nbins=9;

Comment: can you try to add them to the constructor? like `HOGDescriptor hog(winSize, blockSize, blockStride, cellSize, nBins);` and update your questio (with edited code) please. If you additionally can upload your `.xml` file and post the link (+ provide information about training data - winSize, etc), anybody who wants to help you can try it himself without any further comments needed.

Comment: Thanks Micka. I updated my question and shared svmTrain.xml file.